# hive - Regex in Split function not giving output

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Input :

```
[a,b], [c,d], [e,f]
select split(col,'\\,') from table_1;
```

With the above query, am able to split on every comma. (inside and outside the braces)

I need to split only on the commas outside the braces.  so i changed the query as below.

```
select split(col,',(?=\[)') from table_1;
```

regex which i used is correct as for my knowledge but am not able to get output.

Output required:

```
"[a,b]","[c,d]","[e,f]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a space in between your data, so try this regex instead:

```
,\\s(?=\\[)
```

EDIT:

So, I am not sure if you have spaces or not in the column, so here is for both:

**case 1**: without spaces in the column

```
hive> describe a;
OK
t                       string

hive> select * from a;
OK
[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]
Time taken: 0.089 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select split(t, ',(?=\\[)') from a;
OK
["[a,b]","[c,d]","[e,f]"]
Time taken: 0.081 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

**case 2**: with spaces in the column

```
hive> describe b;
OK
t                       string              

hive> select * from b;
OK
[a,b], [c,d], [e,f]
Time taken: 0.084 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select split(t, ',\\s(?=\\[)') from b;
OK
["[a,b]","[c,d]","[e,f]"]
Time taken: 0.082 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: Not working. This returns a single array. ["[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]"]

Comment: Got the exact output i needed using case 1.. Thanks much!